# Put a random generator script on page - it works. Add another one with different names - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I have a function which creates a random name from two lists - a list of adjective and a list of nouns, then combines them to create a random name.  As such, it works fine.

But then I want to add another name generator to the same page that just randomly picks one name from a list and displays it on button click.  So I copied the first function and changed the names (function name, result, placeholder).  When I add both to the page, neither one works.

Same function displayed twice, but the first one combines two words to make a name, and the second one just picks a name at random from a list and displays it.

Since I changed the names on the second function, I think it should work fine.  I don't know why adding the second function makes the first one not work (as well as the second one).

Please check out my jsfiddle here: [jsfiddle 2 different name generators](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmatik2/q8z1hco8/)

The first function is:

```
function generator(){

            var wordlist1 = ["Cool","Masked","Tricky","Lovely","Big","Einstein","White","Rotten",
                            "Blue","Black","Fancy","Red","Purple","Golden","Silver", "Queen", "King", "Gentle", "Tiny", "Teeny", "Silly", "Naughty", "Dear", "Sugar", "Sweet",
                            "Agile", "Amazing", "Awesome", "Dainty", "Bright", "Noisy", "Nosy", "Quick", "Quiet", "Sassy", "Saucy", "Sharp", "Timid", "Touchy", "Snazzy", "Pretty", "Lazy",
                            "Spirited", "Flaky", "Flashy", "Elfin", "Fiery", "Ferocious", "Bubbly", "Fussy", "Fiery", "Funny", "Gentle", "Gloomy", "Good", "Grouchy", "Crabby", "Cool", "Cranky", "Curious", "Hearty", "Hot-headed", "Electric", "Master"  ];

            var wordlist2 = ["Cavy","Moose","Llama","Duck","Bear","Eagle","Tiger",
                            "Rocket","Bullet","Knee","Foot","Hand", "Yuki", "Aspen", "Tut", "Apollo", "Bandit", "Smokey", "Misha", "Snow", "Snowball", "Lord", "Prince", "Princess",
                            "Giant", "Dwarf", "Sally", "Bee", "Star", "Dragon", "Buddy", "Lady", "Urchin", "Champion", "Cherub", "Oreo", "Soul", "Guy", "Emir", "Earl", "Admiral",
                            "Baron", "Baroness", "Bishop", "General", "Chief", "Emperor", "Majesty", "Master", "Boss", "Captain", "Duchess", "Skipper", "Czar", "Tyrant", "Raja", "Dame",
                            "Colonel", "Khan", "Knight", "Duke", "Jewel", "Mate"  ];

            // Random numbers are made 
            var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist1.length);
            var randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist2.length);
            var name = wordlist1[randomNumber1] + " " + wordlist2[randomNumber2];           

            //alert(name); //Remove first to slashes to alert the name

            //If there's already a name it is removed  
            if(document.getElementById("result")){
                document.getElementById("placeholder").removeChild(document.getElementById("result"));
            }
            // A div element is created to show the generated name. The Name is added as a textnode. Textnode is added to the placeholder.
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            element.setAttribute("id", "result");
            element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
            document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element);
        }
```

So for the second one, I just changed the names (from generator to wholegenerator), removed the "+ " " + wordlist2[randomNumber2]" part (because I'm only using one word for these names, not combining two), and added "onclick generator()" and "onclick"wholegenerator()" to the respective buttons.

Why can't these two functions work together on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8z1hco8/3/) illustrating the solution working.  The puzzle was solved by realizing that your JavaScript code was only being loaded after the DOM had been loaded.  When you use global functions, you must ensure the functions are defined before the HTML that references them is processed.

```
function generator() {
    // Add your own words to the wordlist. Be carefull to obey the showed syntax
    ...
```

Moving this script into the head will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you add your javascript code before html, it is working fine.
```

check here  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8z1hco8/10/)